# How can I set Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true in JVM?

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot, jvm-arguments

In one of my computers, there is [JRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine#Java_Runtime_Environment) 1.8.0_45 and in another machine there is [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK).

I want to set the JVM flag **Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true**, but where can I write this piece of configuration?

Comment: It goes on the `java` command line.  There is no single place to put that that will fix all of the commands that use Java.

Comment: Assuming that you are concerned about the "log4shell" vulnerability, my advice would be to look for the vulnerable log4j2 JAR files and update them to version 2.15 (or later).

Comment: (And, seriously `1.8.0_45`??  That is many, many security patches behind.  Fix that too.)

Comment: you can also add `-Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true` to the environment variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`.

Comment: Maybe ... but there are issues with using `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` ...

Comment: The latest Java 8 is not vulnerable.  But the latest is 1.8.0_311.  The Java 8 updates table in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history summarizes the patch releases that include security fixes.  Basically ... lots of them.

Comment: For the time being, I want to use JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS with the value -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true. Is this safe to avoid log4j vulnerability? @StephenC Due to legacy applications running on the machine which only runs in older versions but I will add the patches.

Comment: Given that you'll have to test the System Property change in every application, why not just test against version 2.15+ and make no code changes?  See [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70315727/where-to-put-formatmsgnolookups-in-log4j-xml-config-file/70315976#70315976)

Comment: I am using  jdk 1.8.0_262 /64 bit - is there any way replicate this issue in local ?  or how do i ensure Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true  fix is  working or not ?

Comment: remember that this parameter works only for log4j2 version >=2.10

Comment: Disabling lookups with system properties is discouraged since CVE-2021-45046

Comment: better use the even newer 2.16 version of log4jcore

Answer (score 3):

If possible, upgrade to Log4j version 2.15.0.

If upgrading is not possible, then ensure the *-Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true* system property is set. Use the this command:

```
java -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true -jar myapp.jar
```

Also worth reading on mitigation:

- *[Log4J2 Vulnerability and Spring Boot](https://spring.io/blog/2021/12/10/log4j2-vulnerability-and-spring-boot)*
- *[Inside the Log4j2 vulnerability (CVE-2021-44228)](https://blog.cloudflare.com/inside-the-log4j2-vulnerability-cve-2021-44228/)*